# Is $ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1} $ equal to $\infty$ or to $1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital, infinity

What is 
$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}$?

When I look at the function's graph, it shows that it goes to $\infty$, but If I solve it by hand it shows that the $\lim \rightarrow 1$

$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1} =$ $ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}{\frac{x}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}} =$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}=$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{0+0} = \ 1$

what is wrong here?

Comment: Forget the algebra for a minute, just look at the function and think about it for a while.  What happens what you plug in $x = 1000$?  How many times does a thousand and one go into a million...?

Comment: division by 0 while doing limits? that the hint

Comment: Your last equal is simply wrong, but use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Why do you say $\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac 1 {0+0}=1$?

Comment: @fleablood I made a mistake, did not get attention to this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is $+\infty$. Note that $\lim_ {x\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}}=+\infty$, not $1$.

Comment: I just didt pay attention that 1/0 = infinity, thanks

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong is

- to write "$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{0+0}$": an expression such as $\frac{1}{0+0}$ doesn't make sense.
- to write that "$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{0+0}$" is equal to $1$. If there is a way to give a meaning to this limit, it will certainly not be $1$ but rather $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on the sign of the denominator.
- to constantly mix up the two kinds of sentences "the **function tends to** infinity" and "the **limit** of the function **is equal to** infinity".

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{x+1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac1x}=\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

You  cannot always reinvent the wheel! It's a  basic result that the limit at infinity of a rational function is the  limit of the ratio of the leading terms of its numerator and denominator.

In other terms, here:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Writing the fraction as follows may clear it up:
$$
\frac{x^2}{x+1}
= \frac{x^2-1+1}{x+1}
= \frac{x^2-1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1}
= x-1 + \frac{1}{x+1}
\to \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$x\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$